# What is an example a zero divisor in the 10-adic integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I am having trouble seeing why zero divisors exist in the $n$-adic numbers.  Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ where here I want to think of this ring as the inverse limit of the rings $\mathbb{Z}/10^{n}\mathbb{Z}$, so a subset of their direct product.  If $(a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},...)(b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},...)=(0,0,0,...)$ then we must have $a_{0}=2$ and $b_{0}=5$ (or vice versa), but then the only possible pairs for $(a_{1},b_{1})$ are $(50,2)$, $(25,4)$, $(20,5)$, $(5,20)$, $(4,25)$, and $(2,50)$, but none of these would give elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ ($a_{1}$ has to be congruent to $2$ mod $10$, so it must be $2$, but then $b_{1}$ is $50$ which is not congruent to $5$ mod $10$).

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments $(2,5)$ is not the only possibility, but it is one possibility: assuming $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$ are relatively prime and $a_{n-1}b_{n-1}\equiv 0$ (mod $10^{n}$), we want to show that there exists $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ such that $a_{n}=10^{n}s_{n}+a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n}=10^{n}t_{n}+b_{n-1}$ and $a_{n}b_{n}\equiv 0$ (mod $10^{n+1}$).  But the remainder part of $a_{n}b_{n}$ (mod $10^{n+1}$) is $10^{n}(s_{n}b_{n-1}+t_{n}a_{n-1}+k)$ and $s_{n}$ and $t_{n}$ can be chosen so that $(s_{n}b_{n-1}+t_{n}a_{n-1}+k)$ is any number.  How to show that $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are also relatively prime?

Comment: I looked there but I do not see specific examples.  Can you point me to specific examples?

Comment: Take $F=\ldots4106619977392256259918212890625$, see [this page](https://divisbyzero.com/2008/12/29/a-10-adic-number-that-is-a-zero-divisor/). "such that $F^2=F$ (in other words $F$ is an idempotent element of the $10$-adic numbers). Of course, with a little algebra we can turn this into $0=F^2-F=F(F-1)$. In other words, both $F$ and $F-1$ are zero divisors in the set of $10$-adic numbers."

Comment: Following Dietrich's recipe you can always take $b_i=a_i-1$. So $(5,4)$, $(25,24)$, $(625,624)$, $(90625,90624)$ etc.

Comment: Ah okay I see, thank you

Comment: [Here](https://nesinkoyleri.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/borovik_4.pdf) is a detailed answer, on page $33-34$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde and Jyrki Lahtonen I am new to trying to understand these numbers.  Am I right that multiplication and addition works exactly as with normal decimal numbers (here I am now thinking of $n$-adics as infinite decimals), i.e., we just "carry" the quotient?

Comment: also $...1010010112\times...1533203125$

Comment: @reuns I do not see $5^{n}$ anywhere can you explain?

Comment: In other words $a=\lim_{n\to \infty}5^{2^n}$ converges to a non-zero 10-adic integer and $a^2=a$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919274/96384