# What is $99999\dots$?

Tags: analysis

Is there any way to make sense of expressions with infinitely many digits to the left of the decimal point?

There's a famous proof that $0.999\dots=1$ which starts with $x=0.999\dots$ and derives $10x=x+9$, therefore $x=1$. We can do the same thing with an infinite string of $9$'s to the right of the decimal point: Assume $x=9999\dots99$

Then $10x=9999\dots990$

Then $10x+9=9999\dots999=x$

Finally we get $10x+9=x$

So $x=-1$
$\qquad$ My question is: Is it possible to make sense of the expressions ''$99999\dots9$'' and ''$99999\dots90$'' and the algebraic manipulations above? If not, why does this work for $x=0.999\dots$ and not for $x=999\dots$?

Comment: Pay attention. You can't work with $9999...$ the same way you work with $0.9999...$

Comment: $99999$$\cdots$ looks as if it is bigger than any positive integer

Comment: No, we can't...

Comment: The sequence of infinitely many 9's does not mean anything at all. Whenever you deal with infinitely long expressions you are really dealing with limits. That's how you _define_ the meaning of $0.999\ldots$.

Comment: Note that $0.999...$ is a sum of the form $\Sigma_{k=1}^n 9 \cdot 10^{-k}$, which converges while $999....$ would be the sum $\Sigma_{k=1}^n 9 \cdot 10^{k}$ which diverges to positive infinity.

Comment: Your $10x+9=99999\cdots=x$ looks unjustified. If this were meaningful, you would have $10x+9=99999\cdots9$ where you would know the final digit while with $99999\cdots$ you would not

Comment: Are you suggesting that $10x+9=x$ is not true for $x=\infty$?

Comment: Let $x=10^n-1$, then $10x=10^{n+1}-10$, $10x+9=10^{n+1}-1 \neq x$

Comment: However, if $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 10^{n}-1$, then you do get to conclude $10x+9=x$. In the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$ that limit is infinite. With respect to the 10-adic metric, the limit is $-1$.

Comment: I think the question is now clear, asking why this works with $0.999\dots$ but not $999\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with these equations is the "$\dots$". In infinite expressions such as the infamous $0.9999\dots$, the ellipsis represents a limit. In the decimal case, what it means is the limit of the sequence $$
0.9, 0.99, 0.999, \text{ and so on}
$$
which you can prove converges in various ways, for example it is trivially increasing, and is bounded above by $1$. The manipulations that follow are valid *assuming the limit exists*. Let $x=0.9999\dots$ (i.e., the limit of the above sequence). Then:\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& 0.9999\dots\\
10x&=&9.9999\dots\\
10x&=&9+x\\
x &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}
Now, we turn to your expression $999\dots$. The ellipsis here would indicate that this is meant to be the limit of the sequence $$
9, 99, 999, \text{ and so on}
$$
Of course, the limit doesn't exist under the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, but if you pretend you don't know that, you can do the kind of manipulations you wrote out and say that *if* the limit $999\dots$ exists, it is $-1$.

It looks very similar to an expression for a [$p$-adic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), which are typically represented by an infinite string of base-$p$ digits for some prime $p$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919274/why-are-p-adic-numbers-and-p-adic-integers-only-defined-for-p-prime/) and its answers for why it should be a prime). In $p$-adic spaces, you can do those sorts of manipulations you wrote down and make meaningful sense of them. Wikipedia presents the nice example of the $5$-adic $$
\dots1313132 = \frac13
$$
Indeed, you can represent any rational number as an infinite string of base $p$ digits. So, for example, in $5$-adics again, you can write $$
\dots 44444 = -1
$$
which follows from the same kind of manipulations you did: Let $x = \dots 4444$. Then (keep in mind I'm in base $5$ here):\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \dots 4444\\
10x &=& \dots 4440\\
10x+4&=&\dots 4444 = x\\
4x +4&=&0\\
x &=&-1
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Really appreciate for your edit which makes it more clear...

Comment: It's a big shame your question got such a negative response from some users. It is really a very natural and reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot express numbers that way. Technically, you could let $x=99999\dots$, but it makes absolutely no sense to write $10x = 99999\dots0$ since there are an infinite number of $9$'s before the $0$. Even if you could, solving $10x+9=x$ involves subtracting $x$ from both sides. Since $x$ is infinite, $10x+9$ is also infinite and you cannot subtract one infinity from another like that.

Comment: "but it makes absolutely no sense to write $10x = 99999...0$ since there are an infinite number of 9's before the 0" -- a priori there is no reason why you couldn't have numbers (or some other mathematical object) given by a sequence of digits indexed by $\omega + 1$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries but then I would have thought $99999\cdots9 \not= 99999\cdots$

Comment: Well, maybe. Since these things are not yet defined in any way, who knows what it means to multiply one by 10?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that in writing $9999\dots0$ we are assuming $99999\dots$ has an ending point which it does not since there an infinite number of $9$'s

Comment: @bobeyt6, it does not imply that "999..." has an ending point, any more than writing ordinals as $0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \omega, \omega+1, \omega+2, \ldots, \omega \cdot 2, \ldots$ implies that there are finitely many natural numbers.

Comment: @MeesdeVries writing $99999\dots0$ means that there is a $0$ at the end of the infinite number of $9$'s

Comment: Yes, and that's fine. You can have an infinite linear order followed by another larger element. Consider writing down a subset of the rational numbers $\{0, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7, \ldots, 1\}$. Does that notation suggest that there is a largest natural number?

Comment: 'you cannot subtract one infinity from another like that.'  But in $x=0.999...$ when you multiply x by 10, you get $10x=9.999...$  Then $10x-x$=$9$. Here you just subtract one infinity from another  
@bobeyt6

Comment: This is different since $0.999\dots$ is not infinite even if it has an infinite number of $9$'s

Comment: what about $x=0.8888...$ $10x=8.8888$ Then $10x-x$=$8$

Comment: In which $x=\frac89$ which matches its decimal expansion. My point is is that you cannot subtract one infinity from another but you can subtract one convergent sum from another, such as $0.999\cdots$ or $0.888\cdots$,

Comment: (+1) , although $x=9\cdots 9$ with infinite many nines should already be avoided.